# Structure pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am getting quite confused alot about pointers in structures. 
I have a piece of code which i do no understand fully yet,
the code:

```
typedef struct{
    int fildes // basic file descriptor
    char* location // location would be somewhere in /dev/tty*
}context0; // structure named 'context' containing the 2 elements above.

context0 someContext; // create a context struct

process(&readLocation); // takes reference from the function 'readlocation'
// i do not know what this process function does.

uint_16_t readLocation(int8_t *buffer, int16_t n, SomeContext){ // buffer pointer, n size read, and fidles 
context0 foo = *(context0*) SomeContext; // ???? What Is Going ON right here ????
return read(foo.fd, buffer, n);
}
```

I have changed some of the names but its the code which i do not fully understand.

Some questions:

- since `readLocation` function is passed as a reference should it not be defined as `void*` ? infront of the `uint_32_t`
- main question: what does the `context0 foo = * (context0*) SomeContext;` do?

Comment: This is not a valid piece of C++ code. Is `SomeContext` supposed to be a type or a variable. If it is a variable, what is ts type?

Comment: someContext is a structure of the type context0 if anotherContext would be added someContext could be seen as the context for the serial input where is read from, and anotherContext would be the serial output where will be writen to

Comment: Otherwise: question 1: no, any type of function can be passed as parameter. question 2: it seems like a cast to pointer type `context0*` , and the a dereference. (But as I said it is not a valid code in the first place.)

Comment: Then it should be declared so. like this: `uint_16_t readLocation(int8_t *buffer, int16_t n, context0 *SomeContext)`, which renders the later cast pointless.

Comment: yes but the concept of function pointers then? if the whole function is used as a paramters as in printf(somemessage()); then ok, but it takes the reference from the function with the & ampersant function, so i would expect to see a function declared with int/void*

Comment: what about struct terminos oldtio, newtio, these do not require some special cast why would context0 someContext differ o.o?

Comment: Let me google that for you: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

Answer (score 0):

ok so it seems that (context0 *) is infact a typecast which is done by (int)bar to set some other type to the type of 'int'. this is done to set the variable bar to the type of context.

this typecast can also be done to a pointer type cast wich would be done as (int*) or (struct name*), or in this case (context0 *).

lastly the pointer outside of the parenthisis dereferences the structure pointer to acces whatever it points towards and places this information in the struct context0 foo.

why this is nessesary i do not know but the syntax points to this.

thanks, oh ur welcome np

and thank u  Gábor Angyal, but cannot give points or whatever level 1